# Should I report the user for "I don't know" comment or is it a valid contribution?

Tags: discussion, comments

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1006508/why-is-uk-english-version-larger-than-a-general-english-version?noredirect=1#comment1393380_1006508) and I'm not clear on how to interpret the comments form a certain user. This is how I perceive it but I'd like to get a second opinion on my interpretation.

1. Me: I wonder about X.
2. User: We can't answer that. (No improvement suggestion nor explanation.)
3. Me: The comment is for improvement suggestion.
4. User: I know what comments are for. (Still no suggestion nor explanation.)

I fear that I might be missing something and that I get annoyed at the user (for him being a donkey), while he's actually trying to tell me something, (which makes me a donkey). Advice?

Comment: There's a difference between a comment saying "I don't know" and one saying "We can't answer that". Just saying you don't know is useless, and is of Yahoo Answers quality. But saying "*We* can't answer that" is more useful because it suggests you've asked an unanswerable question. Ideally they'd also say "...because" though.

Comment: Well, the comments are gone now, so no one that didn't see them already can now answer this question.

Comment: @JonW I see your point. Although I need to point out that "we can't answer that" **without** stating why is also as useful as  a pocket on the back of the shirt. In fact, it creates this aura of collective condemnation over the question but it's created by a single user and hardly constructive to the case. But I'll be willing to grant it the benefit of doubt.

Comment: @GrantWinney That's because I clicked the flag and reported it as not constructive. (It was **after** that fact that I realized that I'd like a second opinion in order not to make further decisions based on emotional reasons).

Comment: @AdamDavis I'll definitely assume good intentions. And since the comments are gone now, I only want to get the community's opinion for future reference. And since I've got it already, I'll know how to proceed next time. Thanks.

Comment: As the person who submitted the comment in question, I can say that, it most defiantly was more "there is no possible way we can know the reason one .ISO is 4MB larger then another" then a comment saying "I don't know".  I later went on to explain the reason, any answer we could provided, would be pure speculation on "our" the communities part.  I didn't feel a need to explain in detail, because I issued a close vote, I consider that my reason.

Comment: @Ramhound I never saw any comment about the speculations. And according to my history in the top bar, there was no such comment posted. Maybe it got cut off or something. At any rate, the claim about the speculation-only is invalid because **someone might** actually know the reason. Someone who's worked with those things, perhaps. Also, my question stated a clear discrepancy so speculation or not, it's of interest to learn why. Usually, when technical stuff doesn't behave in the expected, logical way, there's something to be learned. In fact, someone **did** answer.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten - The comment was deleted before you saw it obviously.  I know what I submitted as a comment though.  The answer that was submitted was based on speculation, they didn't actually know, if thats the reason.

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Be nice... Saying my unwillingness to speculate is because of ignorance is rude and I take it as a personal attack on my character.  Your question was closed by 4 other people, who also thought, answers would be highly opinionated.  *So I must not be that ignorant....*  I am indeed done, I have nothing to say to you, I shouldn't have even provided and explanation I seriously regret doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Report? No. The user was not rude towards you.

If you don't like the comment just ignore it, and you can also flag it as "not constructive":

> [image]

Comment: Got it. And no, the user was in no way rude. Pointless remark and not constructive, in my opinion, but fully politely made. Also, I saw that he claims to be more extensive in another comment, which I haven't seen nor have any mentioning of in my logs but I'm willing to chalk that up to technical issues. +1 for the image, by the way.

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help. :-)